# How to get name with conditional?

Tags: c#

I have `valuesFrom, valuesTo, values` values.
How to get values from List<> auto increment +1 with another parameter?
I want to save all in the `listview`.

How to get `rows[valuesFrom]` -> `rows[valuesTo]` with parameter of them?

My code like:

```
valuesFrom = Int32.Parse(txtFrom.Text);
valuesTo = Int32.Parse(txtTo.Text);
List<string> lstNameImage = new List<string>();
for (int i = valuesFrom; i < valuesTo; i++)
{
    string values = name + " " + i;
    lstNameImage.Add(values);
}
sizeImage = Int32.Parse(txtSize.Text);
fontImage = txtSize.Text;
g.DrawImage(DrawText(lstnameImage.Text.Trim(), fontImage, .......); //I don't know how to get lstnameImage?
```

Example: user input to textbox: `valuesFrom = 4, valuesTo = 55`.
Then loop to this and create `List<> lstNameImage` to hold all data.

Class `DrawImage(DrawText(parameter1, parameter2,. ....))` only accept parameter 1 is a image but `lstNameImage is List<>` contain many images.
So, I don't know how to get all `lstnameImage` to DrawText into an image.

Comment: What is your desired end result? Your question is unclear to me.

Comment: You see `lstnameImage.Text.Trim()`. Normal, I add 1 image to DrawText(image). But  lstnameImage is the List<>. I can't know values bind in lstnameImage. I will update example.

Comment: What is your lstnameImage ? where did you declare ti ? in your code I see lstNameImage but this is a list of strings and as I know a list doesn't contain a property named Text

Answer (score 0):

This simple Linq should do the trick

```
var list = values.Skip(valuesFrom).Take(valuesTo - valuesFrom).select(p => name + " " + p);
```